# Frontend Backend communication clarification

Tags: security, web, frontend, backend

Pretty new to web development so apologies for the probably obvious question.

I see everywhere that the frontend makes requests to the backend and not the client directly.

But let's say I have a react app, that runs on the browser of course, and it makes Ajax calls to the backend, so it's basically the client makes the call and not the frontend server which serves the index.html and whatnot.

Does that mean, from a security perspective, that I should permit access to both frontend and backend servers from clients?

Much thanks!

Comment: How do you distinguish "frontend" and "client"? Can you show any document that tells you that the frontend performs the request, and not the "client"?

Comment: https://twitter.com/loganrakai/status/891073175114489856?lang=he
He shows in this post a differentiation regarding FE/BE, in such a way that the client can't access directly the BE. I've seen it in many different places but this shows what I meant

Answer (score 0):

usually, today FrontEnd(FE) , it is just Codes that runs in the client browser.
generally speaking, Modern Architecture is built from FronEnd (code that runs in Client Browser like React, angular, HTML, JS etc.) that communicates with a server (Node JS, PHP, etc.)
a few years back there where a FrontEnd Server that generates the Client-side for the users that cold FronendServer (that server had FE DB etc) and that server communicated with BE server that kept more sensitive data.

Comment: "Does that mean, from a security perspective, that I should permit access to both frontend and backend servers from clients?" - how does your answer relate to this question? Please share more details about this such that others can learn from it

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer! If you may expand a little regarding the security concerns that would be great :)